# WPF (mvvm, caliburn.micro) button click inside a listview item

Tags: wpf, listview, button, caliburn.micro

I have a simple listview and listviewitem structure.

The Heart of the ListView.xaml is like the following

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="Movies" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMovie}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <v:ListItemView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

and the heart of the ListTtemView.xaml is the following:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
    <Button cal:Message.Attach="RunOperation" cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=DataContext}" Content="Run"/>
</StackPanel>
```

in the ListViewItemViewModel, I have a method called RunOperation and the scenario is when the user clicks the button in a listviewitem, the method RunOperation should be called. However, I get an exception: 'No target found for method RunOperation.'

I have read that the caliburn micro doesn't work in a case like this and if this is the case, I realised that I still don't know how to make it work the simple WPF way.

Apparently, RunOperation method cannot be found so I tried few combinations of cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding ...}" but no help.

Thanks

Comment: Did you delete your `ListItemView.xaml.cs` file?

Comment: no, but I added nothing to this file

Answer (score 3):

If someone is still looking for a solution, here is what I did, With reference to caliburn.micro and interactivity in the xaml like below,

```
xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro.Platform"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

```
<Button Content="Run">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
      <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="RunOperation">
         <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding}" />
      </cal:ActionMessage>
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

The view model button click method will be

```
public void RunOperation(object obj)
        {
            //Do your things
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your xaml involving button is not available in question, am not sure if you have already tried this, but following should help you hit the function on Button's click event.

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action RunOperation]"/>
```

Comment: yes, I already tried this but it doesn't change anything. thank you

Comment: this still routs the event to the child control not the parent

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about caliburn.micro.
But the normal WPF approach would be this

Step 1:
Create a `Command` in your `ViewModel`

```
class ViewModel
{
    ...
    public ICommand RunOperationCommand { get; }
    ...
}
```

Step 2: Bind to it

```
<Button Command="{Binding RunOperationCommand }" />
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not the caliburn.micro solution. And I don't know if there is a valid caliburn.micro solution for situations like this.

But the following works:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.RunOperationCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" />
```

Comment: by the way, this is referring to a method which is in the parent viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, plus I was trying to get around it using a normal WPF approach.

I had Buttons being created dynamically inside a List Control which a source of was Bindable Collection of Sensors (my class).
You need to make sure you add a reference to the  "xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" and
"xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org" on your UserControl or Window.

Can find all the information and examples on Caliburn Micro Docs:
[CaliburnActions Docs](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/actions)

```
<UserControl x:Class="BeckerGasApp.Views.MapView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BeckerGasApp.Views"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org">
    <Grid>          
            <Grid>                 
                <ItemsControl x:Name="Sensors" Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Sensors, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >                               
                                <Button Background="Transparent" Content="{Binding SensorName}" >
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="Sensor">
                                                <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding SensorName}" />
                                            </cal:ActionMessage>
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                </Button>                          
                    </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it inside a `listview` I had the following extra tag `cal:Action.Target` to be able to access `ÀctionMessage` for an item in `listview`.

```
<ListView
    x:Name="LV"
    Background="Transparent"
    BorderBrush="Transparent"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

    <ListViewItem>
        <Button x:Name="StartPage">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <cal:Action.Target>
                        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="StartPage">
                            <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding}" />
                        </cal:ActionMessage>
                    </cal:Action.Target>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>

            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Width="210" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="../Assets/img_home.png" Stretch="None" />
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource font_style}" Text="Home" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>                            
</ListViewItem>
```